# ValueAnimator has an infinite call of cancel () if it is called from startListener

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, listener

I have two instances of `ValueAnimator` that are started inside `onClickListener` - one moves the `view` up, another moves the same `view` down. Each animation has a `startListener`, so that when one starts, the second one is called `cancel()`. Ie if the animation, say up, interrupt in the middle, - cause the animation to go down, then `cancel()` should work, and it works, but if i set `startOffset` on both animations, `cancel()` in `startListener` works many times (as in a loop), and then i have a `stackOverFlowError`.

I noticed that the same error will be without `startOffset`, but if i call both animation starts at the same `view` without calling `cancel()` at the first animation. But `cancel()` is called inside `startListener`(!). And  `startListener` does not works when the animation starts native with `anim.start()`, only after the end of the startOffset's delay.

Code:

```
Float firstLevelUp = 200f;
Float firstLevelDown = 0f;

long duration = 1500l;

ValueAnimator valueAnimatorView1Down = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(firstLevelUp,firstLevelDown);
ValueAnimator valueAnimatorView1Up = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(firstLevelUp,firstLevelDown);


public void initAnim(final View view){
    valueAnimatorView1Down.setDuration(duration);
    valueAnimatorView1Up.setDuration(duration);

    valueAnimatorView1Down.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            if (valueAnimatorView1Up.isStarted()) {
                valueAnimatorView1Up.cancel();
                valueAnimatorView1Down.setCurrentPlayTime(duration - valueAnimatorView1Up.getCurrentPlayTime());
                Log.i("Down View1 animation " , "STARTED WITH CANCEL");
            }else {
                Log.i("Down View1 animation " , "STARTED WITHOUT CANCEL");
            }

        }


        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            Log.i("DownView1 animation " , "CANCELED");
        }
    });

    valueAnimatorView1Up.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {


            if (valueAnimatorView1Down.isStarted()) {
                valueAnimatorView1Down.cancel();
                valueAnimatorView1Up.setCurrentPlayTime(duration - valueAnimatorView1Down.getCurrentPlayTime());
                Log.i("Up View1 animation " , "STARTED WITH CANCEL");
            }else {
                Log.i("Up View1 animation " , "STARTED WITHOUT CANCEL");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            Log.i("Up View1 animation " , "CANCELED");
        }
    });


    valueAnimatorView1Down.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

            view.setTranslationY((Float) valueAnimatorView1Down.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });


    valueAnimatorView1Up.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                view.setTranslationY((Float) valueAnimatorView1Up.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });
}

   public void startViewAnimation(boolean side) {

    if (side) {
        Log.i("Down animations ", "start()");
        valueAnimatorView1Down.setStartDelay(800);
        valueAnimatorView1Down.start();


    } else {
        Log.i("Up animations ", "start()");
        valueAnimatorView1Up.setStartDelay(800);
        valueAnimatorView1Up.start();
    }
  }
}
```

Questions: why is the `cancel()` on the `onStartListener` invoked in loop + `stackOverFlowError`, if i change the animation to the second one, before the `startOffset` is over in the first (although if i call a new animation after the start delay - everything works correctly) and how to fix it?

Comment: I think it is because you are setting the `currentPlayTime`. It starts the animation as a new object while the old one is holding reference to the view and therefore not deinitalized so you'll be getting the `StackOverflowException`. Trying removing the the setter from the listener callback

Comment: @HawkPriest , I removed `setCurrentTime` from `onStartLisneters` and assigned it before the call to `anim.start ()`, but this did not solve the problem. May I do something wrong, or maybe deal in something else. I tried deleting the `updateListeners` in `onStartListener` (yes, even so), and then set again, but this did not solve the problem